# How to retrieve object_id without hardcoding values for schema and stored procedure name

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

In a stored procedure on Azure synapse Dedicated SQL pool I need to get the object_id of the currently executing stored procedure

SQL server has available extremely useful system variable `@@PROCID`

however `@@PROCID` is not available on Azure Synapse Analytics nor Analytics Platform System (PDW)

```
DECLARE @procid  VARCHAR(100) = ( SELECT OBJECT_ID([my-schema].[my-stored-proc-name]))
```

above works yet I am looking to avoid having to hardcode my schema and stored procedure name just to retrieve object_id

Essentially I just need a programmatic way to get `[my-schema].[my-stored-proc-name]` in my code inside a stored procedure as per

```
DECLARE @ProcName NVARCHAR(128) = '[my-schema].[my-stored-proc-name]'
DECLARE @procid   VARCHAR(100)  = (SELECT OBJECT_ID(@ProcName))
```

without having to hardcode both my schema and my stored procedure name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can use system dynamic management view `sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests`  to retrieve the currently running stored procedure.

```sql
select substring(command,charindex('exec',command)+5,50) as current_SP FROM sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests where status='Running' and 
command like 'exec%' order by start_time
```

**Stored Procedure:**

```sql
create PROCEDURE usp_find_2
AS
BEGIN
select substring(command,charindex('exec',command)+5,50) as current_SP FROM sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests where status='Running' and 
command like 'exec%' order by start_time desc 
END
```

This stored procedure selects the `command` column from the `sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests`, which contains the command that is currently being executed. The `substring` function is used to extract the name of the stored procedure from the command. The `charindex` function is used to find the position of the string 'exec' in the command, and the `substring` function is used to extract the name of the stored procedure starting from the position of 'exec' plus 5 characters. The `where` clause filters the results to only show the currently running stored procedures.

- When this stored procedure is executed with the command,

```sql
exec usp_find_2
```

current stored procedure name is returned.

[image]